# PHP - How to efficiantly (memory) process a large array to generate running totals

Tags: php, arrays

Backstory, each user has data stored on a mysql table.

Each row has lots of different times eg time1 and time2 + another 65 other type of time and some other columns with strings.

On the server (EC2 based PHP) we generate paginated running totals for each of the 65 different type of time, (page totals, prev page and grand) and and page has 18 rows.

These totals are generated (currently) by getting all the rows from the DB and storing them in an array.
Then looping the array with paginated logic and adding them up. Which results in a paginated array:

```
        Array -> 
         page1->
           'pageTotals' => [.....]
           'prevPageTotals' => [.....]
           'grandTotals' => [.....]
        ........
         page800->
           'pageTotals' => [.....]
           'prevPageTotals' => [.....]
           'grandTotals' => [.....]
```

Then with the totals array and the array from the DB I use paginated logic to output all the data either onto the site or into a paginated pdf file.

For most users that have up to a 1000 rows this is no issue and quick and not memory hungry but is some user had 10000 rows then this is slow and memory heavy due to the large sized arrays this whole process can take up to 17 seconds

I am wondering if anybody knows of a better way to deal with this problem

The infrastructure is EC2 PHP server and the data has to be avaible live without any type of caching etc

I appolgize for the lack of code but I can expand/ add snippets as required

Thank you

Result is something like in the picture but with 64 totals and around 1000 pages of 18 rows each
[image: Example]

Update points:
All user data is required, and cannot be done in mysql as some processing is applied to the results

Comment: This question cannot be answered adequately because there's too little information in the question. Putting all the needed information in the question might make it too long. Currently I see two things you could try, but I can't tell if they're possible: 1. Create the totals with a MySQL query. 2. Don't use all the user data.

Comment: Without seeing more of the code is hard to see what the problem might be, but I wonder if this data is retrieved with 1 query and then processed or if you are running multiple queries for building this array. Because in my experience you can process 100.000 rows in an array within a (few) second(s) and most of the time the biggest slowdown is having multiple queries instead of one. Secondly, it might also be faster to use an array with objects instead of an array of arrays.

Comment: Or this might be a time to adapt a Big Data mindset and denormalize your data, updating running totals on `INSERT`, rather than `SELECT`. It's hard to tell.

Comment: @Jerry the problem with that is the number of rows per page can vary between 11 and 25

Comment: A well-considered data model would take that into account.

Comment: I know you said no caching, but if you cache the totals and add a trigger(s) to the user data table(s) that updates the totals whenever the data tables are updated, it might be much faster than calculating the totals every time.

Comment: Is your performance issue always or only with the PDF version?

Comment: @ChrisHaas after running some tests and some optimisation, all processing apart for the pdf takes 4 seconds and 62mb memory for 10000 rows which is fine. But when generating pdf with the data it is 17 seconds total and nearly 100mb memory which makes me think I need to rethink the pdf generation. I currently use fpdf which may be slow so I might have to find an alternative

Comment: I would be curious if just for a test if you could close and re-open your table HTML table, maybe every 1,000 rows, and see if you notice a considerable performance change.